# Spring boot - interceptor - add to MySQL

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, model-view-controller, spring-data-jpa

I have calculated the execution time of all the APIs through spring boot interceptor and I am able to log it to the console. Now, I need to push the execution time and API to MySQL database. Is there anyway to handle this? Do I need to create a model, controller and service for the interceptor to push to the db?